# How to prevent vertically stacked navigation drop downs from covering other nav links in mobile

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, responsive-design, navbar

I'm making a responsive top navbar that becomes vertically stacked when viewing on smaller screens.  My problem is that in mobile view when you hover over a navigation item to expand the dropdown, the dropdown menu covers the other navigation links.

I'm trying to make the lower navigation elements move down to make room for the dropdown menu when a navigation link hovers over.  I want to avoid using jQuery or Bootstrap and prefer to only use HTML and CSS if possible.

JSFiddle link (Be sure to resize the window or view on mobile):
https://jsfiddle.net/adilworth/fzrnvukm/3/

What I've tried:
I have played around extensively with changing the CSS position element but I cannot seem to get it to behave as I want.

HTML:

```
<ul id="navigation">
<li><a href="#">Product 1</a>
<ul>
<li><a href="#">rx.com </a></li>
<li><a href="#">Resources</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Copay Cards</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li><a href="#">Product 2</a>
<ul>
<li><a href="#">e.com </a></li>
<li><a href="#">Resources</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Copay Cards</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Informational Video</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li><a href="#">INSOMNIA EDUCATION</a>
<ul>
<li><a href="#">Complete Night Sleep Resources</a></li>
<li><a href="#">sleep.com </a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li><a href="#">PAIN MGMT EDUCATION</a>
<ul>
<li><a href="#">Safer Pain Management Resources</a></li>
<li><a href="#">painmanagement.com </a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li><a href="#">MEDICAL AFFAIRS</a>
<ul>
<li><a href="#">Request Clinical Reprints</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Schedule a Scientific Session </a></li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
/* Main Navigation */
#nav {
    position:relative;
    width:620px;
    margin:0 auto;
    margin-top:50px;
    padding:10px;
}

ul#navigation {
    margin:0px auto;
    position:relative;
    float:left;
}

ul#navigation li {
    display:inline;
    font-size:12px;
    font-weight:bold;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    float:left;
    position:relative;
}

ul#navigation li a {
    width: 234px;
    padding:10px 25px;
    color: black;
    text-decoration:none;
    display:inline-block;
    background: #ebebeb;
}

ul#navigation li a:hover {
    background:#ebebeb;
    color:black;
}

ul#navigation li a.first {
    border-left: 0 none;
}

ul#navigation li a.last {
    border-right: 0 none;
}

ul#navigation li:hover > a {
    background:#ebebeb;
}

/* Drop-Down Navigation */
ul#navigation li:hover > ul
{
/*these 2 styles are very important,
being the ones which make the drop-down to appear on hover */
    visibility:visible;
    opacity:1;
}

ul#navigation ul, ul#navigation ul li ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
/*the next 2 styles are very important,
being the ones which make the drop-down to stay hidden */
    visibility:hidden;
    opacity:0;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 99999;
    width:234px;
    background:#ebebeb;
}

ul#navigation ul {
    top: 43px;
    left: 1px;
}

ul#navigation ul li ul {
    top: 0;
    left: 181px; /* strong related to width:180px; from above */
}

ul#navigation ul li {
    clear:both;
    width:55px;

}

ul#navigation ul li a {
    background:none;
    padding:7px 15px;
    color:#black;
    text-decoration:none;
    display:inline-block;
    border:0 none;
    float:left;
    clear:both;
    width:150px;
}
```

Comment: What's the desired output? I don't understand from your description...

Comment: I'm wanting the navbar to move down to make room for the dropdown menu instead of the dropdown menu covering the lower navigation links.  Right now in mobile view when you hover over a nav link the dropdown menu covers the rest of the nav links.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in using `position: absolute;`. Then you find that using `visibility: hidden/visible` isn't good too :-)

```css
/* Main Navigation */
#nav {
    position:relative;
    width:620px;
    margin:0 auto;
    margin-top:50px;
    padding:10px;
}

ul#navigation {
    margin:0px auto;
    position:relative;
    float:left;
}

ul#navigation li {
    display:inline;
    font-size:12px;
    font-weight:bold;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    float:left;
    position:relative;
}

ul#navigation li a {
    width: 234px;
    padding:10px 25px;
    color: black;
    text-decoration:none;
    display:inline-block;
    background: #ebebeb;
}

ul#navigation li a:hover {
    background:#ebebeb;
    color:black;
}

ul#navigation li a.first {
    border-left: 0 none;
}

ul#navigation li a.last {
    border-right: 0 none;
}

ul#navigation li:hover > a {
    background:#ebebeb;
}

/* Drop-Down Navigation */
ul#navigation li:hover > ul
{
/*these 2 styles are very important,
being the ones which make the drop-down to appear on hover */
    display: block; /* here change visiblity > display */
    opacity:1;
}

ul#navigation ul, ul#navigation ul li ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
/*the next 2 styles are very important,
being the ones which make the drop-down to stay hidden */
    /*visibility:hidden;*/
    opacity:0;
    /*position: absolute; */
    display: none; /* change visibility > display */
    z-index: 99999;
    width:234px;
    background:#ebebeb;
}

ul#navigation ul {
    top: 43px;
    left: 1px;
}

ul#navigation ul li ul {
    top: 0;
    left: 181px; /* strong related to width:180px; from above */
}

ul#navigation ul li {
    clear:both;
    width:55px;

}

ul#navigation ul li a {
    background:none;
    padding:7px 15px;
    color:black;
    text-decoration:none;
    display:inline-block;
    border:0 none;
    float:left;
    clear:both;
    width:150px;
}
```

```html
<ul id="navigation">
<li><a href="#">Product 1</a>
<ul>
<li><a href="#">rx.com </a></li>
<li><a href="#">Resources</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Copay Cards</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li><a href="#">Product 2</a>
<ul>
<li><a href="#">e.com </a></li>
<li><a href="#">Resources</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Copay Cards</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Informational Video</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li><a href="#">INSOMNIA EDUCATION</a>
<ul>
<li><a href="#">Complete Night Sleep Resources</a></li>
<li><a href="#">sleep.com </a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li><a href="#">PAIN MGMT EDUCATION</a>
<ul>
<li><a href="#">Safer Pain Management Resources</a></li>
<li><a href="#">painmanagement.com </a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li><a href="#">MEDICAL AFFAIRS</a>
<ul>
<li><a href="#">Request Clinical Reprints</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Schedule a Scientific Session </a></li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<div id="doral_resources">
<h4>Resources</h4>
</div>
<p><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /> <br /><br /></p>
<div id="doral_copaycards">
<h4>Copay Cards</h4>
</div>
```